# "Favorite Question" badge awarded multi times

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, notifications, bookmarks

As you can see, every time somebody favorites a question, which is already favorited by at least 25 users, **it appears that**(although actually it's not) an extra "Favorite Question" badge is awarded to me.

[image]

Comment: Related Meta SE post: [Badge Notification Repeats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283748/badge-notification-repeats).